# Нужна ли запятая после можно?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после "можно": Исправить людей можно, лишь показав
их такими, каковы они на самом деле.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужна.

Читаем у [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113):

> Деепричастный оборот, в начале которого стоят частицы ***только,
>   лишь,*** интонационно не отделяется от предшествующей части
>   предложения (при чтении пауза перед ним не делается), но запятая перед
>   ним обычно ставится: *Понять это произведение можно, **только учитывая
>   условия его создания**; Выучить иностранный язык можно, **лишь
>   постоянно занимаясь им**.*
>
> Но (при тесном слиянии оборота со сказуемым): *Они встретились
>   **только будучи уже взрослыми.***

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна, потому что деепричастный оборот "лишь показав их такими, каковы они на самом деле" должен быть обособлен запятыми.